# GDAL ReadAsArray slow?

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf

I am currently working with [GOES-R](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/goes/) on AWS. I've downloaded recent data, which is in the netCDF file format. Specifically I am using band 3 (M3C03).

When loading it into GDAL, it is taking upwards of 5 minutes.

```python
goes_dir = "goes"
goes_files = glob.glob(goes_dir + '/' + str(doy) + '/18/*M3C03*.nc')
goes_files[:3]

['goes/257/18/OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M3C03_G16_s20172571815379_e20172571826146_c20172571826188.nc',
 'goes/257/18/OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M3C03_G16_s20172571845379_e20172571856146_c20172571856196.nc',
 'goes/257/18/OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M3C03_G16_s20172571830379_e20172571841146_c20172571841193.nc']

go = gdal.Open('NETCDF:' + goes_files[1] + ':Rad')
import time
start_time = time.time()
goes_arr = go.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
# --- 277.96904397 seconds ---
```

What can I do to speed it up? The files are only 50 MB maximum.

Comment: You could look at using the netCDF library as shown here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185352/transpose-large-netcdf-with-gdal-ncl-nco-or-cdo and also demonstrated to improve performance here http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2016-November/045573.html. That last link also suggests using GDAL translate to modify the raster so you could try that also

Comment: Can you point some test data that can be downloaded directly?

Comment: I linked to the AWS page. That's as direct as it gets with AWS.

Comment: @Freighty netCDF4-python opens the file effortlessly. GDALWarp still takes 5+ minutes to warp the netCDF, which is understandable considering its still using GDAL under the hood.

Comment: Can you just use the netCDF4 library to get the data into a numpy array and then convert to tif or other format? Such as here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file

Comment: Are you still seeing the performance issue?  If so, what version of GDAL are you using?  I believe some enhancements were made with GDAL 2.2.x to better support GOES-R processing.  However I have run into some performance issues with GDAL 2.3.x that I'm currently investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an easy way to fix this. My solution was to warp it to a known projection GeoTIFF, which takes several minutes but only needs to be done once.